# How to investigate Apex : Your session has expired Error?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have an apex application and from time to time, I'm having the error : Your session has expired

I'm trying to investigate it but I'm quite struglling with the source of the problem.

When I run the following query :

```
select *  from apex_workspace_activity_log where application_id = Identifier and error_message is not null order by view_date desc
```

I'm getting the following result

[image]

Basically it's saying, there was an error while executing a certain Ajax plugin.

As far as I know, I don't have any Ajax plugin in these pages. Almost all my PL/SQL code is full with **apex_debug.message** to monitor is but I can't see anything wrong.

Does anyone know how to investigate such issues please ? For example how to get the list of all Ajax Plugins in the application or something like that ?

Thanks, cheers,

Comment: You could see those types of entries from more than just plug-ins you've installed. For example, that's pretty typical for charts. Generally, when you have a chart, the page starts to render and the chart data is requested via Ajax. Do you have charts on those pages? At any rate, I would look for the request just before the errors start. It's likely that something is happening, such as a request with an invalid session, that's causing APEX to destroy your session and then the subsequent requests fail.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I don't have any charts on the page. When you say  "I would look for the request just before the errors start." Do you know how to that please ?

Comment: Well, before we go down that path, let's rule out the easy stuff first. Go to the App > Shared Components > Security Attributes > Session Management (tab). What are the values for Maximum Session Length in Seconds and Maximum Session Idle Time in Seconds?